# Watching variable i in a for loop with lldb

Tags: c++, lldb

Having just switched to lldb, I'm trying to do the equivalent of gdb's `watch i` being I'm inside a for loop in my code.

```
(lldb) f
frame #0: 0x0000000100000664 a.out`MaxPairwiseProduct(numbers=size=5) + 4 at max_pairwise_product.cpp:19 [opt]
   16     // Find max value in vector
   17     
   18     for (int i=1; i<numbers.size(); i++) {
-> 19       if (numbers[i] > numbers[i-1]) {
   20         second_max = max;
   21         max = numbers[i];
   22         if (numbers[i] < max && numbers[i] > second_max)
(lldb)
```

As you can see above, `int i` has already been declared.

Checking which watchpoints I have yields

```
(lldb) watchpoint list -b
Number of supported hardware watchpoints: 4
No watchpoints currently set.
(lldb)
```

Now trying to set a watchpoint to i (according to the [lldb reference](https://lldb.llvm.org/lldb-gdb.html)) I get

```
(lldb) wa s v i
error: Watchpoint creation failed (addr=0xffffffffffffffff, size=0, variable expression='i').
error: cannot set a watchpoint with watch_size of 0
(lldb)
```

I don't understand why this is, being the variable has been declared. Googling the error didn't help much as most issues seem to be related with hitting the max number of watchpoints, which is not my case as can be seen above. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I changed the way I was compiling the program to `clang++ -Wall -g -o max_pairwise max_pairwise.cpp` and it started showing me the right information, including tracking the value of `i`

Comment: This is probably a bad error message (rather, not giving an informative error message) when a variable referenced isn't available at the current location. Your rebuilt command line example doesn't have any optimization, I'm guessing that you did have it in the first example.  Or you were stopped at a different point in the program between the two runs.  You definitely should have gotten an error message about what the problem was instead of this behavior though, watchpoints are a little rough in lldb.